# mongo query + Preference for a particular key in mongodb + node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Consider i have the following document structure in my mongoDb.

```
{
"A":"asdas",
"B":true
},
{
"A":"ywebw",
"B":false
},
{
"A":"opmsjns",
"B":false
}, ...........
```

The Documents length may be 1000 with value of Key B as either true or false.

From my front-end they will request 10 documents at a time. So i implemented MONGOQUERY with skip(0) and limit(10) , skip(10) and limit(20),....this continues for consecutive request.

Now my requirement is to give `preference to Key B with true first`.

So after key B with true finished , the key B with false should proceed, at the same time, we have to maintain pagination(skip and limit). If key B with value rue is finished for 38 documents then, 4th request should return documents with key B false..

Please share your ideas.Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Use sorting if you want to give preference to B: true, use below code with pagination

```
db.getCollection(<collection name>).find({}).sort({B:-1}).skip(30).limit(10)
```

It will give you 8 records with B:true and 2 records for B:false on 4th page as you want.

Comment: we are not sure by which nth request the true will end??